# Measurement Puzzle Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-measurements

I have to solve the following Question:

Bob asks you to prepare an electron on which he will perform a single Quantum measurement of either $\sigma_x$ or $\sigma_z$ without telling you which measurement he did. After his measurement, he will give you the electron back, so you can perform your measurement on it. Your Task is to retrodict with certainty the result Bob got if he measured $\sigma_x$ and the result he got if he measured $\sigma_z$. What should you do?

Does anyone have a tip for me, how to solve this Kind of puzzles?

Comment: In the quantum mechanical frame one does not "give" particles left and right. To get an answer one has to have boundary conditions . In addition any method of measuring the properties of a specific partilcle introduces interactions. If it is a homework question it is badly defined.

Comment: I may be missing something, but this problem seems impossible to me. In fact, isn't the impossibility of this problem exactly what makes BB84 (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB84) secure?